# Is there a way to change "Tab Key" Function in Google Sheets to that of "Enter/Return Key". Like a way to change the Key Bindings Temporarily

Tags: google-sheets, keyboard-shortcuts

If you Select two columns, and keep pressing tab key, it starts the selection of the cell from A1, Then moves to B1 & then to A2, Then to B2 and so on.

I need to be able to use Enter key to perform this function. Is there a way to temporarily change the Tab key Function to  Enter Key.

If there is no option in Google sheets - Is there an Add-on that will help me with this. I am not that good with Script Editor.

Comment: Is this an [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/)?

Answer (score 0):

There is no feature in Google Sheets nor in Google Apps Script to do this. If you absolutely need to make the **Enter** key send a **Tab** key event, you will have to install some utility that lets you remap keys per application.